# When $p<q$ there is a solution to $qx+py = c$, but not when $p>q$. Why?

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, linear-diophantine-equations

For linear diophantine equation:
$qx+py = c$ , where $p$ is a prime and $q$ is a natural number, 
why is it that if $p<q$ then there is a solution to the equation, however when $p>q$ then there is no solution to the equation?

I just don't see why either number has to be greater for there to be a solution; I'm assuming it has to do with the fact that $p$ is prime. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is $q$?  It doesn't seem to appear anywhere in your computation except as a bound on $p$...

Comment: @XanderHenderson I have edited the question, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That statement isn't true.  As long as $q$ is not a multiple of $p$, there will be a solution for $x$ and $y$ for any integer $c$.  What leads you to think otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

$x+2y=1$ has a solution namely $x=3$, $y=-1$.